# Is $x^2$ differentiable at $0$ if we change the domain to $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> We define the function $x^2$ to be from $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ to the real numbers. Is the function differentiable at $0$?

I think the answer is yes because the function is continuous at $0$, since $0$ is in the domain, and there is a sequence $(1/n)$ that converges to $0$, so $0$ is also a limit point.

Also, I think this function is not differentiable at any other point in the domain since we do not have any other limit point besides $0$.

The part that I'm not so sure about is that we only have the right-hand limit. There is no left-hand limit so I'm not sure if we can apply the definition of the derivative. But I remember in Darboux's theorem that functions can be defined to be differentiable at their endpoints.

Comment: You need to add the definition of "differentiable at a point".  In a calculus book, that is only defined when the function is defined in an interval containing the point.  Perhaps in some other context we want to define it anyway. But since that is non-standard, that definition should be included in the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be your function. Yes, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ because:

- $0$ is a non-isolated point of the domain of $f$;
- the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x$ exists (it is equal to $0$).

And it is not differentiable anywhere else, since every other element of the domain of $f$ is an isolated point.